# Angular 7: Enabel and Disable buttons according to number to form fields filled

Tags: angular

I very new to `angular 7` and I came up with a situation where I have two buttons :

1. submit
2. Check

I have to enable `check button` when 3 form fields are filled i.e

```
semester, branch and subject
```

on the other hand I want to enable submit button when all the 4 fields are filled i.e

```
semester, branch and subject, image
```

I am using `FromValidation` and can successfully enable the `submit` button when 4 fields are filled, now the problem is how to enable the `check button` when 3 form fields are filled

**component.html**

```
<app-teacher-header></app-teacher-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="!checkAssignment">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
                [(ngModel)]="assignment.name" name="name" [value]="assignment.name" disabled>
              </div>

              <!-----------------SEMESTER  ----------------------->
              <div class="form-group" #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="assignmentUploadValidation">
                  <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="assignment.semester" name="semester"
                      formControlName="semester">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let semester of semesters" [value]="semester.semester">
                            {{semester.semester}}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                      <div *ngIf="(validations.semester.invalid && validations.semester.touched) || validations.semester.dirty">
                        <small *ngIf="validations.semester.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Subject is required</small>
                      </div>
                    </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <!----------------- /SEMESTER  ----------------------->


              <!-----------------BRANCH  ----------------------->

            <div class="form-group" #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="assignmentUploadValidation">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Select Branch</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="assignment.branch"  [(ngModel)]="teacher.branch" name="branch" formControlName="branch"
                (openedChange)="branchChanges($event)">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branchs" [value]="branch.branch">
                    {{branch.branch}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <div *ngIf="(validations.branch.invalid && validations.branch.touched) || validations.branch.dirty">
                  <small *ngIf="validations.branch.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Branch is required</small>
                </div>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <!-----------------/BRANCH  -----------------------> 

              <div class="form-group" #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="assignmentUploadValidation">
                  <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="assignment.subject" [(ngModel)]="teacher.subject" name="subject"
                      formControlName="subject">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [value]="subject.subject">
                            {{subject.subject}}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                      <div *ngIf="(validations.subject.invalid && validations.subject.touched) || validations.subject.dirty">
                        <small *ngIf="validations.subject.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Branch is required</small>
                      </div>
                    </mat-form-field>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"  #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="assignmentUploadValidation">
                <input type="file" name="image" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" formControlName="image">
                <div *ngIf="(validations.image.invalid && validations.image.touched) || validations.image.dirty">
                  <small *ngIf="validations.image.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Branch is required</small>
                </div>
              </div>


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpload()" [disabled]="userform.invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <app-check-assignment *ngIf="checkAssignment" 
        [receivedFromTeacherAssignment]="recivedAssignment" [justMsg]="parentMsg"></app-check-assignment>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCheckAssignment()">check</button>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Teacher } from 'src/app/shared/teacher.model';
import { TeachersService } from '../teachers.service';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared/shared.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export interface Assignment {
  name: string,
  semester : number,
  branch: string,
  subject: string,
  image: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teacher-assignment',
  templateUrl: './teacher-assignment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teacher-assignment.component.css']
})
export class TeacherAssignmentComponent implements OnInit {
  private teacher = Teacher
  private recivedAssignment : {name: string, assignment: string}
  semesters = []
  branchs = [];

  subjects = [];

  checkAssignment = false;
  parentMsg : string = '';
  assignment : Assignment = {
    name: "",
    semester: null,
    branch: "",
    subject: "",
    image: ""
  }

  assignmentUploadValidation = new FormGroup({

     semester: new FormControl('',
     [

       Validators.required
     ]),
     branch: new FormControl('',[
       Validators.required
     ]),
     subject: new FormControl('', [
       Validators.required
     ]),
     image: new FormControl('', [
       Validators.required
     ])
   })

  constructor(private teacherServ: TeachersService, private sharedServ: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get validations() {
    return this.assignmentUploadValidation.controls;
  }


  onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    for( var key in this.assignment) {
      fd.append(key , this.assignment[key])
    }

    if(fd) {
      this.teacherServ.uploadAssignment(fd)
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res),
        err => console.log(err)
      )
    }

    console.log("assignment: ",this.assignment)
  }

  onCheckAssignment() {
    this.checkAssignment=!this.checkAssignment 
    console.log("THis is assignment", this.assignment)
    this.parentMsg = "demos"
    this.teacherServ.checkAssignment(this.assignment)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.recivedAssignment = res.result[0]
        console.log(this.recivedAssignment)
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCheckAssignment()" [disabled]="assignmentUploadValidation.controls.semester.invalid || assignmentUploadValidation.controls.branch.invalid || assignmentUploadValidation.controls.subject.invalid">check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `valueChanges: Observable<any>` from FormControl class to track changes of field and when they have values check button.